# "Download declined" on android market

Tags: android, google-play

People are able to see my paid app "Mypod unlock key" on honeycomb devices, but after they purchase an error, "Download declined" the app doesnt install. it downloads and installs fine on pre-honeycomb devices.

The log shows

```
I/vending ( 3174): [1] AssetDownloader.downloadDeclined(): Download declined for asset 954210361404590979 (org.my_pod.mypodunlockpaid:0) [DOWNLOAD_PENDING]: 4
```

Copy protection on market is off.

Has anyone seen this "download declined" eror? its crazy - not explanation or reason at all...

Answer (score 0):

this is the standard error when you are trying to download a paid app from your developer account.